# Pyspark - Regex - Extract value from last brackets

Tags: regex, pyspark

I created the following regular expression with the idea of extracting the last element in brackets. See that if I only have one parenthesis it works fine, but if I have 2 parenthesis it extracts the first one (which is a mistake) or extract with the brackets .

Do you know how to solve it?

```
    tmp= spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 'foo (123) oiashdj (hi)'), 
        (2, 'bar oiashdj (hi)'),
    ],
    ['id', 'txt'] 
)


tmp = tmp.withColumn("old", regexp_extract(col("txt"), "(?<=\().+?(?=\))", 0));

tmp = tmp.withColumn("new", regexp_extract(col("txt"), "\(([^)]+)\)?$", 0));

tmp.show()

+---+--------------------+---+----+
| id|                 txt|old| new| needed
+---+--------------------+---+----+
|  1|foo (123) oiashdj...|123|(hi)|  hi 
|  2|    bar oiashdj (hi)| hi|(hi)|  hi
+---+--------------------+---+----+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract the substring between parentheses with no other parentheses inside at the end of the string you may use

```
tmp = tmp.withColumn("new", regexp_extract(col("txt"), r"\(([^()]+)\)$", 1));
```

**Details**

- `\(` - matches `(`
- `([^()]+)` - captures into Group 1 any 1+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `$` - at the end of the string.

The `1` argument tells the `regexp_extract` to extract Group 1 value.

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/Ra7VjU/1).

**NOTE**: To allow trailing whitespace, add `\s*` right before `$`: `r"\(([^()]+)\)\s*$"`

**NOTE2**: To match the last occurrence of such a substring in a longer string, with exactly the same code as above, use

```
r"(?s).*\(([^()]+)\)"
```

The `.*` will grab all the text up to the end, and then backtracking will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Use it with the single line flag.

```
\([^\(\)]*?\)(?!.*\([^\(\)]*?\))
```

https://regex101.com/r/Qrnlf3/1